# How to convert 16 bit hex color to RGB888 values in C++

Tags: c++, colors

I have `uint16_t color` and need to convert it into its RGB equivalent. The hex is set up so the first 5 bits represent red, next 6 for green, and last 5 for blue.

So far I have found something close to a solution but not quite due to truncation.

```
void hexToRGB(uint16_t hexValue)
{

    int r = ((hexValue >> 11) & 0x1F);  // Extract the 5 R bits
    int g = ((hexValue >> 5) & 0x3F);   // Extract the 6 G bits
    int b = ((hexValue) & 0x1F);        // Extract the 5 B bits

    r = ((r * 255) / 31) - 4;
    g = ((g * 255) / 63) - 2;
    b = ((b * 255) / 31) - 4;

    printf("r: %d, g: %d, b: %d\n",r, g, b);
}

int main()
{
    //50712=0xC618 
    hexToRGB(50712);    
    return 0;
}
```

The example above yields `r: 193, g: 192, b: 193` which should be `r: 192, g: 192, b: 192` I have been using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720937/c-defined-16bit-high-color) question as reference, but I essentially need a backwards solution to what they are asking.

Comment: Expressions like `((r * 255) / 31)` don't give you exact results, unless you use floating point arithmentic.

Comment: Obviously, there are fewer values representable in 5 bits than there are in 8 bits, so not all values can round-trip perfectly. Also, your conversion fomulas are strange - 0 would be converted to negative value. The simplest approach would be to multiply `r` and `b` by 8 and `g` by 4 - though this won't produce purest white (the whitest it will get is `(248, 252, 248)` ).

Comment: Good luck. 565 is awful and should never have been created. You'll never manage to make the G component match R and B. See the two divisors 31 and 63, and how one is _a bit more_ than twice the other?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using ARGB 1555 or RGB 555 if this is at all possible. You can't even represent grays in RGB 565.

Comment: Something must be wrong with the conversion equations. If you have an input of 0, 0, 0 the output will be -4, -2, -4.

Comment: @gnasher729 power of 2

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It seems irresponsible to suggest that floating-point arithmetic gives exact results, without qualifying your statement. Indeed, integer arithmetic is the only native way to obtain "exact results" .. it's just that they may not be the results the OP is looking for ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442576/how-does-one-convert-16-bit-rgb565-to-24-bit-rgb888

Comment: @gnasher729: green has one bit more because of how humans perceive colour. You'll see that green also dominates if you must convert from colour to grey-scale, using the usually used luminosity conversion: `0.21 R + 0.72 G + 0.07 B`.

Comment: @gnasher729 565 is awful, but was very important at some time, and I was really thankful it was created. 256 color modes did look even more awful, and there was not enough processing power for 24b (and some cards didn't even had 24b, only 32b, which was even worse).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That was what I tried to point out :) ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about the following:

```
unsigned r = (hexValue & 0xF800) >> 8;       // rrrrr... ........ -> rrrrr000
unsigned g = (hexValue & 0x07E0) >> 3;       // .....ggg ggg..... -> gggggg00
unsigned b = (hexValue & 0x1F) << 3;         // ............bbbbb -> bbbbb000

printf("r: %d, g: %d, b: %d\n", r, g, b);
```

That should result in 0xC618 --> 192, 192, 192, but 0xFFFF --> 248, 252, 248, i.e. not pure white.

If you want 0xFFFF to be pure white, you'll have to scale, so

```
unsigned r = (hexValue & 0xF800) >> 11;
unsigned g = (hexValue & 0x07E0) >> 5;
unsigned b = hexValue & 0x001F;

r = (r * 255) / 31;
g = (g * 255) / 63;
b = (b * 255) / 31;
```

Then 0xC618 --> 197, 194, 197, instead of the expected 192, 192, 192, but 0xFFFF is pure white and 0x0000 is pure black.

Comment: Thank you for posting this @Rudy Velthius!

Answer (score 5):

There are no "correct" ways to convert from the RGB565 scale to RGB888.  Each colour component needs to be scaled from its 5-bit or 6-bit range to an 8-bit range and there are varying ways to do this each often producing different types of visual artifact in an image.

When scaling a colour in the n-bit range we might decide we want the following to be generally true:

- that absolute black (eg `00000` in 5-bit space) must map to absolute black in 8-bit space;
- that absolute white (eg `11111` in 5-bit space) must map to absolute white in 8-bit space;

Achieving this means we basically wish to scale the value from (2<sup>n</sup> - 1) shades in n-bit space into (2<sup>8</sup> - 1) shades in 8-bit space.  That is, we want to effectively do the following in some way:

```
r_8 = (255 * r / 31)
g_8 = (255 * g / 63)
b_8 = (255 * b / 31)
```

Different approaches often taken are:

- scale using integer division
- scale using floating division and then round
- bitshift into 8-bit space and add the most significant bits

The latter approach is effectively the following

```
r_8 = (r << 3) | (r >> 2)
g_8 = (g << 2) | (g >> 4)
b_8 = (b << 3) | (b >> 2)
```

For your 5-bit value `11000` these would result in 8-bit values of:

- 197
- 197
- 198  (`11000000 | 110`)

Similarly your six bit value `110000` would result in 8-bit values of:

- 194
- 194
- 195  (`11000000 | 11`)